# Integer, Input, print

Tags: python, python-3.x

The main problem I have is with the printing, It doesn't work as it gives me the error:

> NameError; the name 'ask2' is not defined

I am an absolute beginer in Python, therefore I have literally NO idea how to make it global, or something in those lines.

```
ask = input("-Would you like to 1 input an existing number plate\n--or 2 view a random number\n1 or 2: ")
if int(ask) == 1:
    print("========================================================================")
    ask2 = ""
    while ask2 != 'exit':
        ask2 = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ")).lower()
        # I had no idea that re existed, so I had to look it up.
        # As your if-statement with re gave an error, I used this similar method for checking the format.
        # I cannot tell you why yours didn't work, sorry.
        valid = re.compile("[a-z][a-z]\d\d[a-z][a-z][a-z]\Z")
        #b will start and end the program, meaning no more than 3-4 letters will be used.
        # The code which tells the user to enter the right format (keeps looping)
        # User can exit the loop by typing 'exit'
        while (not valid.match(ask2)) and (ask2 != 'exit'):
            print("========================================================================")
            print("You can exit the validation by typing 'exit'.")
            time.sleep(0.5)

            print("========================================================================")
            ask2 = input("Or stick to the rules, and enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ").lower()
            if valid.match(ask2):
                print("========================================================================\nVerification Success!")
                ask2 = 'exit'  # People generally try to avoid 'break' when possible, so I did it this way (same effect)
            # This 'elif' is optional, it just provides a bit better feedback to the user so he knows he manually stopped
            elif ask2 == 'exit':

        #There are other parts of the code, but it's not necessary

else:
    plate = ""
    # This randomly adds two capital letters (your own code)
    for i in range(2):
        plate += chr(random.randint(65, 90))
    print()
    print(plate)

print("The program, will determine whether or not the car "+str(plate),ask2+" is travelling more than the speed limit")
```

Comment: See how you're referencing `ask2` in the print statement at the very end? It looks like you're defining it inside the `if` statement, and so you can't access it outside that block. Considering defining `ask2` before the `if`.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, as ask2 is linked to ask.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Assuming `ask2` is not defined outside of the first `if` block and assuming you do indeed want to print its value outside the if/else block, you have to define `ask2` before the `if`. Just try it and see what happens. Note however that if the `else` statements are executed, `ask2` won't be assigned to anything.

Comment: Just to make sure, should the outer `if` be indented a little more?

Comment: I don't quite understand, I attempted what you told me, however it ended up badly with syntax errors, haha. The life of a beginner.

Comment: See dursk's answer? Try that.

Comment: I've tried it, but still receive a syntax error

Comment: This can't be your actual code, the line `ask2 = input("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ")).lower()` throws a SyntaxError because you have too many `)`  and this `elif ask2 == 'exit':` will error because there's no code in the block.  It's extra hard to help if the code you're asking for help with doesn't give the error you are asking about. Can you edit it to be your actual code with the problem? (You can leave some code out, but the code posted should give the same error you have) (And it's extra hard for you to make it all work if the individual bits don't work).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Mind If I email it to you? or you email it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently structured like this:

```
if some_condition:
    ask2 = ''
else:
    ...
print(ask2)
```

The problem is that when `some_condition` is `False` and the `else` block executes, after the `if`/`else` when you try to print `ask2`, you're getting the `NameError` since the `if` block never ran and `ask2` is undefined.

You need to do:

```
ask2 = ''
if some_condition:
    ...
else:
    ...
print(ask2)
```

Also, unrelated, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with using `break`.

Comment: Sadly my ask2 is directly linked to my ask. As ask 2 is the option of ask's.
Ask for breaks, I have no idea. A friend suggested the alternative, I am absolute new to programming.

Comment: `ask2` is not directly linked to `ask`. Inside of the `if` block you initialize it to `ask2 = ''`

Comment: Oh, how exactly can I or should I do it then? Please take a look at the start of the code again, I have put the intial part in. Mind giving me suggestions? Thanks

Comment: My initial response already has the answer. You need to set `ask2 = ''` _outside_ of the `if` block it is currently inside of.

Comment: Well I managed to fix it, but instead of printing ask2, I printed out ask. Hahaha how dumb and naive of me. Now the problem is the plate, when I want to print out ask, plate is not defined, any ideas?

Comment: It's the same problem. `plate` is only defined inside of the `else`, yet accessed by the `print` statement outside of that `else` block. You need to set `plate = ''` outside of the `if`/`else`

Comment: That wouldn't work unfortunately, as the code will not work. I tried it but the code didn't work :( it has to be in. Any other way?

Answer (score -1):

The error does say it fairly well. ask2 doesn't seem to be defined.

Did you define int somewhere before? You won't be able to use it, if you haven't declared it somewhere before.

```
if int(ask) == 1:
    print("========================================================================")
    ask2 = ""
    while ask2 != 'exit':
```

it seems like you are calling on ´ask2 being != 'exit' ´ but you did not did not assign any value to it. It just says ask2 ="". Try to assign it some value before, either by defining it or by having one automatically assigned.

Comment: Yes another suggested that; however, that is my problem. I don't know how to create it externally, or globally. I am completely New to Python, absolute begineer.

Comment: Well if you want to call upon it, you will need to define it first. You could probably give it any name and it would work, though it would always be unequal to exit if you did no assign the name "exit" to it. It would help to know what you are trying to archive and why you Need the second variable in the first place.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Also I haven't declared it anywhere before.

Comment: What? Open up a python interpreter and type `int`. It is a built-in type. You absolutely can use it without defining it yourself.

Comment: Well I managed to fix it, but instead of printing ask2, I printed out ask. Hahaha how dumb and naive of me. Now the problem is the plate, when I want to print out ask, plate is not defined, any ideas?